# YAML header of markdown file generates odd table on top of document

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I get a weird output from my YAML header which I do not intend. 
Instead I expect the normal output with title, author and the table of contents of course.

The following code produces the following output:

```
---
title: General Stuff
author: Me
output:
    html_document:
    toc: true # table of content true
    toc_depth: 3  # upto three depths of headings (specified by #, ## and ###)
    number_sections: true  ## if you want number sections at each table header
    theme: united
---
```

generates this output:

[image]

I got this output from GitHub where the file is displayed. Maybe the issue is that GitHub uses some interesting markdown version...?

Comment: that's just the GitHub preview... if you'll be using it with github-pages or similar it will work as intended...

Comment: That's a good point, mb21. thebilly, what's your goal here? Are you trying to host a Pages site? Render GFM on GitHub itself, e.g. in a README? Something else?

Comment: @Chris I am trying to write simple markdown docs to have the text readable in my github repo or when other people render the .md file themselves (via the shared repo of ours) on their machine.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @thebilly. In that case I think the answer I provided below is the right one. (If you were generating Pages sites using Jekyll the YAML front matter should get used, not shown directly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe the issue is that GitHub uses some interesting markdown version...?

YAML frontmatter isn't part of [Markdown itself](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). A regular Markdown processor wouldn't do anything special with it. It would probably render a `<hr>` and some text, maybe ending with a header.

But yes, [GitHub treats YAML front matter specially](https://github.blog/2013-09-27-viewing-yaml-metadata-in-your-documents/):

> Many blogging websites, like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) with [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/), depend on
>   some YAML-formatted metadata at the beginning of your post. You know, the stuff that goes between dashes like this:
>
> ```
> ---
> title: Blogging Like a Boss
> ---
> ```
>
> Starting [September 27, 2013], we’ll render this metadata within GitHub as an
>   horizontal table, for easier reading